# Compatibility Issue: Web App using Node 16, Android App Requires Node 18 in React Native - Need Guidance

Tags: react-native, expo, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm encountering a compatibility issue while working on my web app and Android app. The web app is built using Node 16, but when I try to run the Android app, I'm getting an error stating that "React Native requires Node 18."

I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue. What would be the correct approach to ensure compatibility between the web app and the Android app? Are there any recommended steps or workarounds to handle this situation without compromising the functionality of either app?

Any help or insights into resolving this compatibility hiccup would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

1. Have you encountered a similar compatibility issue between Node versions for web and Android apps?
2. What steps did you take to address the problem, and what were you expecting to happen?

Any information on your experiences and the solutions you attempted would be invaluable. Additionally, if there are any recommended best practices, steps, or workarounds to ensure compatibility without compromising the functionality of either app, I would be grateful for your insights.

Answer (score 0):

This is very common issue when working in multiple project that uses different node versions, the best way you can solve this compatibility issue is to use NVM(node version manager), it helps to maintain multiple node version in a same device.
you can download nvm from this GitHub repo - https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows?tab=readme-ov-file#readme.

check nvm version -> `nvm --version`.
install specific version of a node ->`nvm install <version>`.
check present versions of node -> `nvm list`.
switch to any present version -> `nvm use <version>`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).